# react-native-video: How to manually select video quality

Tags: react-native, mobile, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am building an app for video streaming using HLS from s3.

I want to support the functionality to select Video Quality.

Still unable to find how to select the desired quality.

Can any one please help me in this issue.
If some one knows some react-native api or some other solution, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is the video encoded in multipule renditions? What player are you using?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue. Please post your answer if you find any, this will help alot of developers.

Answer (score 3):

it is possible to select a video quality manually according to the react-native-video documentation use the **selectedVideoTrack** Prop

see https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#selectedvideotrack

example

```
selectedVideoTrack={{
  type: "resolution",
  value: 1080
}}
```

Comment: `selectedVideoTrack` not working for me

Comment: It works only for android

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in `react-native.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    dependencies: {
        'react-native-video': {
            platforms: {
                android: {
                    sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    assets:['./src/assets/fonts/'],
};
```

remove `assets:['./src/assets/fonts/'],` if you don't have fonts directory.

Then in `Video` component select video track like this

```
selectedVideoTrack={{
  type: "resolution",
  value: 1080
}}
```

This solution tested with only Android devices.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71148981/4291272

Comment: my app is crashing on adding above code in the react-native-config file so do you have any idea of this.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple quality renditions in your HLS video, you could use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) for the playback component. Normally this will just switch playback for you, but you can control this manually with the [Quality Switch API](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#quality-switch-control-api).

I.e. you would get the available qualities using `hls.levels` and then iterate through them. Then set `hls.currentLevel` tot he desired quality.

Comment: The OP is asking for react native, not web